# Select only two rows with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a table which is something like this:

```
id title 
11 test
22 test
33 dummy
37 dummy
35 dummy
44 abc
45 abc
```

after select I need only like this one:

```
id title 
11 test
22 test
44 abc
45 abc
```

I wrote like this:

```
select * from content having count(*)=2 group by id, title
```

But I'm not sure why its not returning the expected result..

Comment: As you can see by the answers to this question, you'll have to clarify your question a bit more.. Are these the only columns? Are this the only possibles values of the column title?

Comment: The desired result are `id` and `title` for all titles found exactly 2 times in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `id` from the GROUP BY clause, which means that you can't keep in in the SELECT clause (for SQL Server and most DBMS's).  So, wrap in in a subquery like this.

```
select * from content where title in (
  select title 
  from content 
  group by title
  having count(*)=2 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

> But I'm not sure why its not returning the expected result

Because when you group by `ID` AND `title` the `HAVING` clause will only count UNIQUE COMBINATIONS of those two fields.  It is not just counting the # of records for each `title`.

I think you want this:

```
select * from content 
WHERE title in
( SELECT title 
  FROM content 
  group by title 
  having count(*)=2 
)
```